# CSS Works in chrome devtools, not on live site

Tags: php, html, css, ruby

I have added a coloured background (Australian English!) to my websites navigation and tested it in Chrome DevTools though when I add it to my CSS file nothing happens.

I have checked the CSS file and it is definitely loaded on the page. The selectors look correct.

Forgive me if my terminology is incorrect as I am a graphic designer and inexperienced with web languages.

Any help would be appreciated! CSS I Added:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
.template-index.transparent-menu .main-header {
  /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

Comment: invalid html: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.herpony.com.au%2F invalid css http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.herpony.com.au%2F so im not surprised its not working

Comment: It's look like you didn't start and end Curly brackets in your css code after this line @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {} just like this

Comment: Thanks for your time.
Nogad - I checked that Facebook pixel code and it is valid though for some reason the comment isn't recognised.
Husain - I attempted to put it inline to see if that would make a difference. Fixed the curly bracket. Still doesn't work.

Comment: It may sounds dumb but did you refresh the browser's cache?

Comment: You call this class .transparent-menu but in your navigation code there is no class name .transparent-menu. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works fine for me

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .template-index .main-header {
        /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
        /* For IE 8*/
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
    }  
}
```

I added the missing brackets and remove the `.transparent-menu` which is not present on the web site.

Comment: You are a gun. Thank you very much!!